# Could anyone let me know why the codes variable in not incrementing in the below for loop in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

Could anyone let me know why the codes variable in not incrementing in the below for loop in python. I think it is a very silly mistake but i am not getting it.?

```
for i in df_inc['SHORT_DESCRIPTION_ERROR'].unique():
    codes=0
    code_indices=df_inc[df_inc['SHORT_DESCRIPTION_ERROR'] == i].index.tolist()
    for k in code_indices:
        df_inc.loc[k,'Short_description_error_code']=codes
    codes=codes+1
print(codes)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're overwriting your *codes* variable each step in the loop.
You need to declare your *codes* variable outside of the loop (in line 1).

Answer (score 0):

To fix your move the `code = code + 1` out side the for loop

Also in panda we have better way to do it

```
df_inc['Short_description_error_code']=df_inc['SHORT_DESCRIPTION_ERROR'].factorize()[0]
```